# restart animation of after condition with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a page that contains a div with animation and i want to restart this animation after condition like button click or somthing with jquery is there a way to do that ? 
here is my code :

```
    <div class="block bg-1 network-effect" style="max-height:500px;" id="okd">
        <canvas id="network"></canvas>
            <div class="container1">
                <h2 class="h-lg text-center">All Computer <span class="color">& Tablet Services</span></h2>
                <p class="info text-center">We can Solve your Hardware and Software Problems</p>
                <div class="row text-icon-carousel" id="counterBlock">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="text-icon" data-animation="scaleOut" data-animation-delay="0.5s">
                            <div class="icon-wrapper"><span><i class="icon icon-diag"></i><span class="icon-hover"></span></span>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="number"><span id="ok1" data-to="8000" data-speed="1000">8000</span>+</h3>
                            <p class="text">Computer/Tablet/Laptop
                                <br>Repaired</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have the animation happen when someone clicks a button you would want to do something like this

```
$("selector").click(function(){
    $("selector1").animate({animation});
});
```

Just replace "selector" with what you want clicked, "selector1" with what you want animated and "animation" with what you want the animation to do.